# Valuation ring of $k(x, y)$ of dimension $2$

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

My question is as follows:

> Given a field $k$, is it always possible to find a valuation ring of $k(x, y)$ of dimension $2$?

Answer (score 4):

If by $k(x,y)$ you mean the rational function field in two variables over $k$, then the answer is yes.
Consider the map $v:k[x,y]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ defined as follows: express a polynomial $f\neq 0$ in the form $f=x^ay^bg$, where $g$ is neither divisible by $x$ nor by $y$, and set $v(f):=(a,b)$. Since $v$ is multiplicative it can be extended to the fraction field $k(x,y)$ of $k[x,y]$. Order the group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ lexikographically: $(a,b)<(c,d):\Leftrightarrow (a<c)\vee (a=c\wedge b<d)$. Then $v$ is a valuation having a valuation ring of Krull dimension $2$.

Remark: all valuation rings of $k(x,y)$ containing $k$ can be obtained using the construction just described but replacing $x,y$ with other prime polynomials.

Comment: There's still one point that I don't understand: it's known that the convex proper subgroups of Z^2 correspond to the prime ideals of the valuation ring. Now, there are only 2 convex proper subgroups of Z^2 (namely 0 and 0xZ), which means that the valuation ring has only 2 prime ideals, hence is of dimension 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: @a local property: Ask the same question for a Z valuation.  Only one proper convex subgroup, but two prime ideals in a DVR.